# MobileSafari UILabel

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, safari, uilabel, subclass

I was wondering how the UILabel that displays the website's title in Mobile Safari is created? It's obviously some kind of a subclass and I've attempted to copy it by using my own subclass,but it just doesn't look the same. I also don't know which font they're using :/ Could anyone help me out please? :)

here's my class:

```
 CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
 UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

 CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetLineWidth(c, 1);

 CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextStroke);
 self.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 [super drawTextInRect:rect];

 CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(c, kCGTextFill);
 self.textColor = textColor;
 self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
 [super drawTextInRect:rect];

 self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a basic UILabel with a shadow offset of (0, 1). The only hard part is finding the exactly font and colors that they use. I'm guessing it's just the boldSystemFont with a dark blue font color, and white shadow. You really don't need a subclass for this.

Edit:
UILabel: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/1281/photo1w.png
Mobile Safari Comparison: http://img840.imageshack.us/img840/1538/photo2q.png

I just used the colors given in the interface builder, which are Tungsten (a dark gray) for the text, and Silver (a lighter gray) for the shadow.